# Monad and Structure and interpretation of computer programs

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, scheme, monads, sicp

I couldn't find the word "`Monad`" when I searched SICP 2nd Edition book. Which concept ( or chapters) of SICP relates to Monad ?

Comment: Eugenio Moggi first described the general use of monads to structure programs in 1991. SICP was published in 1984.

Comment: Thanks, But I meant the second edition which came in 2005, I updated the question.

Comment: The second edition was published in July, 1996. Monadic I/O – the first "widespread" monads – appeared in Haskell in May, 1996. Monads didn't become widely known until well into the 21st century.

Comment: I don't understand now why I voted to close this question back then. to answer it, it is Chapter 4, "Metalinguistic Abstraction" IOW "Interpreters". just because Monad *is* the *Interpreter Pattern,* where programs and means to compose them are first class objects (data and functions) of our language. the best intro to Monads is Wadler's "How to Turn Failure into List of Successes", which does not mention the M word once (I think).

Comment: (contd.) although SICP's interpreters are _external_ to the language.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing in SICP addresses monads explicitly: the book was written long before anyone had formalized the concept of a monad as it relates to computer programming (ignoring here the mathematical idea of a monad, which is a different thing). But, some stuff in the book is monadic anyway: lists, for example, are a monad whether you know it or not.

Comment: Is there any alternative book that covers the latest research including monads ? Can you update yur answer if there is one.

Comment: You are wrong.  https://person.dibris.unige.it/moggi-eugenio/ Moggi already transported them from maths to computer science in 1991.  The 2nd edition of SICP dates from 1996.   SICP simply does not cope with, and more generally, they did not want to talk about types.  But it's true that mastering SICP you indirectly understand monads.

Answer (score 3):

SICP uses Scheme.  Scheme allows for arbitrary actions to be chained together.  Nothing stops you from doing so.  In other words, you are basically working in a do-anything monad.  Also, they tend not to be that useful or idomatic in a multi-paradigm language like Lisp (by that, I mean Scheme doesn't take sides; it kind of eschews mutation by making them taboo with the suffix, "!").

In Haskell, you write programs where types limit the kind of action that can occur within said function.  Making an instance monadic lets you compose functions with some restrictions (on the type, as well as the monad laws that the programmer has to take care of).  And you can stack up effects using transformers.

So, monads are not that useful in a language setting like Scheme.  Nor, as Amalloy rightly said, were they invented back then.

EDIT 1: A clarification on the first paragraph.  You can have monads in Lisp (an impure language), just that you don't have the type system making sure you are not mixing effects.  I used `IO` in a `List` monad (Racket + functional/better-monads)   That said, the monad design pattern can be quite useful like how `Maybe` and `List` are used in Clojure/Racket, as Alexis King pointed out.

EDIT 2: For things like State and ST (which are probably what you see in most use cases as many (most?) algorithms take advantage of mutability), monads don't really make much sense.  Also, as I've already pointed it out, you do not get guarantees that you expect out of Haskell in most Lisps.

Comment: -1, while Haskell does use monads for I/O, the `IO` monad is the only "magic" monad, and plenty of monads are useful even in Scheme. The Maybe monad, for example, has made its way into Clojure in the form of `some->`. Your answer is not wrong (there are plenty of reasons Scheme does not use monads as an abstraction), but the first paragraph is a poor argument and is a little misleading.

Comment: I thought I mentioned Scheme, not Clojure (which leans towards FP a lot; I don't know much about it though, aside from the wiki article).  That said, Scheme (well, Racket) does allow you to have multiple effects in a monad.  I tried mixing IO operations in the list monad which performs IO as well.  So, thereby, this isn't really a monad as how it is in Haskell (the type sigs don't match).

However, I do admit that this style of composition can be quite useful in Scheme as well (though I've only seen the maybe put to action anywhere.